# Pre-image of sigma algebra is sigma-algebra, What is wrong with that counterexample?

Tags: measure-theory, examples-counterexamples

Following this definition (*Shilling - Measures, Integrals and Martingales*):

Let $f: X \to X'$ be a map and let $\mathcal{A'}$ be a $\sigma$-algebra in $X'$. Then:

$$\mathcal{A}:= f^{-1}(\mathcal{A'}) :=\{f^{-1}(A'): A' \in \mathcal{A'}\}$$

is a $\sigma$-algebra in $X$.

Now, I probably do something very illegal here but let's consider the following mapping:

$X = \{1, 2\}$, $X' = \{D, \emptyset \}$ where $D$ is arbitrary set.

$\{1\} \mapsto \{{D}\}$

$\{2\} \mapsto \{{\emptyset}\}$

$X'$ is a minimal $\sigma$-algebra in $D$. But it seems $X$ is not, since we do not have mapping from union of $\{1\} \cup\{2\}$ to anything, so $X$ is not closed under countable unions. How is this "counterexample" wrong?

Comment: Do you mean $1 \mapsto D, 2 \mapsto \emptyset$? What are these set brackets doing there? I think you are extremely confused about the definition of a sigma algebra, because you seem to be mixing the concept of sigma algebra and its underlying set.

Comment: @QuantumSpace oh my god yes... I should be mapping back the elements of $\sigma$-algebra of $X'$, not the elements of $X'$... Right?

Comment: Yes, indeed. Does that resolve your confusion?

Comment: @QuantumSpace yes, thank you! As a side question,  why is $\{1\} \mapsto \{{D}\}$ confusing? it's not the same as $1 \mapsto D$ ? Maybe its redundant, but is it wrong?

Comment: Yes that is confusing. Reason: You want to define a function $f: X \to X'$. $1$ is an element of the domain of $f$, but $\{1\}$ is not.

Comment: @QuantumSpace Thank you very much :)